# spring hibernate - dao.save(object) return null pointer exception

Tags: hibernate, spring, persistence, dao

can anyone help me with the following thread? 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?110248-dao.save%28object%29-java.lang.NullPointerException&p=365538#post365538

Many thannks

Answer (score 2):

Spring didn't inject `PatientDaoImp` into your controller. Try this:

```
public class PatientController {

  @Autowired
  private PatientDaoImp dao;
```

Also make sure the following declaration is in your `*-servlet.xml` context file (not the main context file):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pems.web"/>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. For the sake of both mine and yours reputation you should accept the most correct answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

In addition please add:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

to you `*-servlet.xml` file.